# Pandas read excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, file-management

I want to read an excel file using pd.read_excel(''Excel_Sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1'). but I'm getting a extra column named 'Unnamed'

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel('Excel_Sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', index_col = None)
```

```
    Unnamed: 0  a   b   c   d
```

0   0   0   1   2   3
1   1   4   5   6   7
2   2   8   9   10  11
3   3   12  13  14  15[this is my real excel  file which i want to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuy3U.png)